# Can someone help me solve this timer problem in a plugin?

Tags: jquery

My code can be seen here: http://www.jsfiddle.net/wdJM2/  What I want to know is why my kill button doesn't stop the timer function in my plugin. Any solutions??

Comment: That should not be a jQuery plugin; it has nothing to do with jQuery.

Comment: This is a snippet of a larger plugin

Comment: If so, I might take that back.  However, you'll need to decide on the scope of your timer.

Answer (score 1):

`settings` is a local variable.

Each call to `plugin` gets a separate variable.

Your second call does not affect the original `settings` object.

Comment: You should make it a semi-global, inside `(function() { ... })()`.  This way, you get a global variable without corrupting the global namespace.

Comment: not to be a burden but im not sure what that is exactly. can you give me an example or edit the js fiddle file to show me?

Comment: @tom: Looking again, you already have it.  Just put the variable inside of `(function($) { ...`.  Also, _this should not be a jQuery plugin._  It doesn't have anything to do with jQuery.

Comment: So the problem is even bigger I suppose?

Comment: That's not causing a problem; it's just an incredibly stupid design.

Comment: If it's a snippet of a larger plugin, I take that back.  However, you'll need to decide the scope of your timer.  You should probably put the timer and settings in `$(this).data(...)`

Comment: Any chance you can show me in the jsfiddle page? Sorry im a noob

Answer (score 0):

you have two semi-colons for starters:

```
//start the timer
timerFunction();;
```